# What does Exclusive in XOR really mean?

Tags: language-agnostic, math, logic, boolean, xor

Maybe this is just obvious to everyone but can someone explain where XOR (or Exclusive-OR) got its name from? What does the word ***Exclusive*** really mean? Not that it matters, but its just stuck in my head since morning.

```
OR:
0 0 0
0 1 1
1 0 1
1 1 1

XOR:
0 0 0
0 1 1
1 0 1
1 1 0
```

Is it "exclusively 0 for inputs 1,1", "special version of OR" or something else?

Comment: Now that I think about it, wouldn't this question be better suited for http://english.stackexchange.com?

Comment: @zneak: I did think about it but the answer to this question assumes an implicit understanding of boolean logic in my opinion but I'll keep that in mind for next time :) Thanks.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

XOR is an "exclusive OR" because it only returns a "true" value of 1 if the two values are exclusive, i.e. they are both different.

Comment: By "different" you mean one of them is `true` and the other is `false`. So, they are different from each other.

Answer (score 25):

It's what children understand as OR

> You can have chocolate **OR** you can
>   have ice cream

But a programmer would regard this as having both!

Q: "Would you like tea or coffee"
Annoying programmer answer = yes

Comment: aha. I really appreciate this:)

Answer (score 11):

According to Knuth in Vol. 4A of TAOCP, George Boole "...wrote x+y to stand for disjunction, but he took pains to never use this notation unless x and y were mutually exclusive (not both 1).  If necessary, he wrote x+(1-x)y to ensure that the result of a disjunction would never be 2."

XOR is addition with carries being lost.

Comment: A search for "full adder" will show how XOR, AND, and OR serves as the basis for computer addition.

Comment: XOR is addition with carries being lost. +1 for that

Answer (score 8):

It's exclusive in the sense that the two operands must be mutually exclusive (in other words, different).

Comment: I think what zneak meant was that if the operands are different the result is true.

Answer (score 6):

This comes from set theory. Consider that you have two sets A and B, and an element which may or may not be in those sets. The first boolean input is true if the element is in set A. The second boolean input is true if the element is in set B.

If the element is "exclusive" to one set (as in "not shared" with the other) then the XOR operator will return true. Illustration [from wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Venn0110.svg):

[image: exclusive or]

Answer (score 4):

Exclusive in XOR means exactly what it says - one of the two has to be excluded. That is, either one or the other. Neither both, nor none - only one. At least that's how I've understood it :)

Answer (score 3):

It's exclusive as in "only one."  In other words, it's "one of the two, but not both."

Answer (score 2):

I read a nice 'plain English' example today:

> Consider, for example, the English
>   sentence, "You pay me by Tuesday or
>   I'll sue." If that "or" were the
>   logical connective, then the sentence
>   is true when either you do pay me by
>   Tuesday or I sue you; so you could pay
>   me on Monday and I still might sue
>   you. But this particular use of "or"
>   would normally be taken to mean that
>   either you pay me by Tuesday and I
>   don't sue you, or you do not pay me by
>   Tuesday and I do sue you - the
>   so-called "exclusive or".

Hugh Darwen, "An Introduction to Relational Database Theory", p76.