# Difference between or and xor

Tags: boolean

My question is operator related. Today I studied about the operators. Having a confusion. In PHP what is the difference between "or" and "xor". I know both of them are related to Boolean expression. But can't find the original difference.

Anyone please help to understand it more clearly.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php

Comment: OR is true if _at least_ one of the operands is true. XOR is true if _exactly_ one of the operands is true.

Comment: Why is this tagged for MySQL if it is a php question?

Answer (score 72):

It has to do with [mutual exclusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5207240/what-does-exclusive-in-xor-really-mean). `xor` is exclusive. `or` is inclusive.

**Truth Table Comparison**

```
$x $y ($x or $y) ($x xor $y)
0  0    0          0
1  0    1          1
0  1    1          1
1  1    1          0
```

**Note:** the difference in the last case. `xor` is only *true* when either `$x` or `$y` is true, but not both (as the case for `or`).

Answer (score 20):

xor means "exclusive or". That is to say, it's or, but with the single change that if both parameters to the operation are true, the answer is false.

```
A xor B == (A or B) && !(A and B)
```

Comment: And vice versa: `A or B == (A xor B) or (A and B)`. Strange enough I couldn't google this using `or in terms of xor`. If anyone could provide search term to find this please share it.

Answer (score 13):

The difference is with an input of an even amount of 1's (or true's):

```
true or  true = true
true xor true = false

true or  true or  true = true
true xor true xor true = true

true or  false or  true = true
true xor false xor true = false
```

Truth table of OR:

```
  in1  |  in2  | out
-------|-------|-----
   0   |   0   |  0
   0   |   1   |  1
   1   |   0   |  1
   1   |   1   |  1
```

Truth table of XOR:

```
  in1  |  in2  | out
-------|-------|-----
   0   |   0   |  0
   0   |   1   |  1
   1   |   0   |  1
   1   |   1   |  0
```

Answer (score 9):

Another way of putting it: **OR** can be seen as an **AND/OR** connector. One or both choices can be true or chosen. XOR, on the other side, could be described as a "real" OR. Only one of both choices can be true (or chosen).

Comment: red pill XOR blue pill

Answer (score 2):

one is exclusive or -> xor, and the other is or which means at least one of the conditions are met in a truth table. Or is not mutually exclusive, xor is.

Answer (score 1):

enter image description here
[image]

xor is exclusive. or is inclusive